# Sony Spresenseでmbed OSを動かすことはできますか？

Tags: spresense

Sony SpresenseでMbed OSを動かすことはできますか？
また、今後開発ツールとしてMbedに対応するようなことはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答させていただきます。

残念ながら、mbedOS 対応は今のところは予定がありません。
市場の状況を見ながら、今後判断をさせていただきたいと思っています。

今後ともSpresenseをどうぞよろしくお願いします。